What's the name of the Chinese comedian character from Late Night with Conan O'Brien?
In the early years of Conan O'Brien's NBC show (1995 or 1996), he would have a Chinese stand-up comedian perform for a few minutes in Chinese, with English subtitles. It was a man with short hair, five-o'clock shadow (or maybe a goatee), wearing a black suit. His act essentially consisted of insulting Americans for being fat, lazy, dumb, etc. Conan would then invite the comedian to the couch for an interview with the comedian's translator. He would then continue to insult Americans and Conan directly. I'm 99% sure this was another one of Conan's many characters, and I'm 99% sure he had a name instead of just "the Chinese comedian".

It was indeed a bit. It was a character called Wo Li Pai (or Wo Lee Pi, depending on the source). From a synopsis of a 1994 episode in the Paley Center website:

Stephen Lee appears as Chinese stand-up comedian, Wo Li Pai, who does his routine without speaking a word of English and afterwards is interviewed, with the help of his interpreter Chen Eng (Kevin Gee).

He's also briefly mentioned in the Conan O'Brien FAQ (though it claims that it's actually Kevin Gee who played him and Stephen Lee played the interpreter). He was nicknamed the Lenny Bruce of China and mocked Conan (and Americans) mercilessly. I can't find any clips, I'm afraid, but I hope this help.
